# Create a text file containing list of (relative paths to) files in a directory?

Tags: linux, ls

Suppose I am standing on a directory. Inside there's another directory called `inside_dir` containing a huge number of files. I want to create a file containing a list of all the files inside `inside_dir`, listed as the relative path to the files. That is, if there is a file called `file1` inside `inside_dir`, the corresponding line in the list file should be `inside_dir/file1`.

Since the number of files is huge, just doing `ls inside_dir/* > list.txt` won't work because it will complain about having too many arguments.

Comment: The shell complains about a large number of arguments because of the `*`, not `ls`

Comment: @BroSlow I know. `*` expands to all the files in the directory, which can be larger than `MAX_ARG` (I think that's the name of the environment variable?)

Comment: Why the close vote? Leave a comment please.

Comment: Because the question isn't clear and I'm not sure why your answer answers it. `find` and `ls` are different commands, that do different things, in all but specific cases. The shell complains about the `*` expansion, not `ls`, i.e. `find inside_dir/* > list.txt` would cause the same issue.

Comment: @BroSlow My answer is a command that I discovered after posting the question. Note that it is not `find inside_dir/*`. As you point out that would also explode. However `find inside_dir -type f` does not explode. You can try it yourself. If you know how to do the same using `ls`, please, post it. I just accepted my answer because it works and does what my question asks for. If that isn't clear in the question, please, advice me of how I should edit it to make it clearer.

Comment: `ls inside_dir/ > list.txt`?

Comment: @BroSlow `ls inside_dir/ > list.txt` doesn't output paths *relative* relative to the current directory, which I explicitly require in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find inside_dir -type f > list.txt
```